# Finding a guessing number which input from user in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write a code in python 3 which includes a binary serach alghorithm for finding a number. The user will enter 0,1 or 2 for higher or lower point. So, I use this code:

```
def guess():
    i = 0
    # i is the lowest number in range of possible guess
    j = 100
    # j is the highest number in range of possible guesses
    m = 50
    # m is the middle number in range of possible guesses
    counter = 1
    # counter is the number of guesses take.
    print ("Please guess a number")
     condition = input("Is your guess " + str(m) + "? (0 means it's 
     too low, 1 means it's your guess and 2 means it's too high) ")
    while condition != 1:
         counter += 1
         if condition == 0:
            i = m + 1
         elif condition == 2:
              j = m - 1
         m = (i + j)//2
         condition = input("Is your guess " + str(m) + "? (0 means 
         it's too low, 1 means it's your guess and 2 means it's too 
          high) ")
     print ("It took" , counter , "times to guess your number")
guess()
```

Okay, after I run the output looks like:

```
Please guess a number
Is your guess 50? (0 means it's too low, 1 means it's your guess and 2 means 
it's too high) 0
```

And when I enter 0

```
Is your guess 50.0? (0 means it's too low, 1 means it's your guess and 2 
means it's too high)
```

It keeps giving 50.0 for the result but it should give me lower then 50.
Is there any way for taking lower number from the program. Thank you!

Comment: You need to convert the input to an `int(..)`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast your input to an integer, it is reading the input as a string.

```
condition = int(input("Is your guess " + str(m) + "? (0 means it's 
    too low, 1 means it's your guess and 2 means it's too high) ").strip())
```

By `strip`, it will take care of removing whitespaces and newlines before converting the string into an integer.

Comment: Awee You are awesome. It took all my morning and afternoon for finding a solution for it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `input()` will always return a string. Therefore, comparisons like `condition == 0` or `condition == 2` will always return false.

Instead, try checking for `condition == '0'` or `condition == '2'`. More generally, you should probably consider that users may input something other than 0, 1, or 2 and display an error message. That would have helped you catch this bug!

Comment: Awe You are awesome. It gave me different point of view about the code. Thank you so much.